# Sort multi-dimensional array help

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am trying to sort this array by `season_number` however I am not really sure which function to use as I assume I need a custom sort? Any ideas?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [season_number] => 7
            [show_id] => 21
            [show_seasons_id] => 14
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [season_number] => 6
            [show_id] => 21
            [show_seasons_id] => 31
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [season_number] => 1
            [show_id] => 21
            [show_seasons_id] => 40
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [season_number] => 2
            [show_id] => 21
            [show_seasons_id] => 41
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`usort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function with the 'compare' function:

```
function compare_my_elements( $arr1, $arr2 ) {
   $s1=$arr1["season_number"];
   $s2=$arr2["season_number"];
   if( $s1 == $s2 ) return 0;
   return ( $s1 > $s2 ? 1 : -1 );
}

usort( $my_md_array, compare_my_elements );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    $newArr[$key] = $val['season_number'];
}
array_multisort($newArr, SORT_ASC, $array);
```

where $array is the array that you printed out.

Comment: nice one... though the `$link` probably would have to become `$val`.

Comment: @xtofl ah, yes you are correct.  Sorry this is a piece of frequent code that I use and I copied and pasted.  I used to use usort like your example, however, I found that this way is a tiny bit faster.  Let me know if you have different findings.

Comment: I didn't tune it.  This one may be faster due to the 'keys' being extracted only once, while with the user-defined function, the key-extraction logic is needed for each compare operation in the sorting algorithm.